# How can I deploy multiple deployments in Kubernetes cluster at the same time?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-container-service

I have multiple .NET microservices in my architecture and for each one I have created a deployment object and now I attempt to deploy to the Azure container service running kubernetes. When I run a kubectl apply -f services.yml I always have a few failing pods. But if I run these deployments individually then they all work.
The error I receive in summary is:
failed to start container and The system cannot find the file specified.
The pods status shows as: CrashLoopBackOff

My services file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service1-deployment
  labels:
    app: service1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: service1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: service1
        image: iolregistry.azurecr.io/panviva/doc:v1
        command: ["service1.exe"]
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regsecret
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service2-deployment
  labels:
    app: service2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: service2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: service2
        image: iolregistry.azurecr.io/panviva/doc:v1
        command: ["service2.exe"]
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regsecret
```

In reality I have many more deployments in the file but you get the Idea.
I have tried splitting these deployments into different files and calling kubectl apply -f service1.yml -f service2.yml but I still receive the same error. I believe it is something to do with the kubernetes starting multiple pods at once. How can I fix this?

EDIT:
Describing a failing pod yields the following result:

```
Name:           getdocumentservice-deployment-528941145-cpt30
Namespace:      default
Node:           e527bacs9002/10.240.0.5
Start Time:     Fri, 29 Dec 2017 05:02:31 +0000
Labels:         app=getdocumentservice
                pod-template-hash=528941145
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/created-by={"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicaSet","namespace":"default","name":"getdocumentservice-deployment-528941145","uid":"793ff632-ec55-11...
Status:         Running
IP:
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/getdocumentservice-deployment-528941145
Containers:
  getdocumentservice:
    Container ID:  docker://774d7bd23ce3da64a747db4c3737123a56069de97c7b3c3cd11e898e3c9e0e42
    Image:         iolregistry.azurecr.io/panviva/doc:v1
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://iolregistry.azurecr.io/panviva/doc@sha256:1bc4f4840707c0174a6d9665828042b04045da2d30e77d96fa325c2f3ae245a6
    Port:          <none>
    Command:
      ./modules/GetDocumentService/GetDocumentService.exe
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       ContainerCannotRun
      Message:      container 774d7bd23ce3da64a747db4c3737123a56069de97c7b3c3cd11e898e3c9e0e42 encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) extra info: {"ApplicationName":"","CommandLine":"./modules/GetDocumentService/GetDocumentService.exe","User":"","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\app\\m
odules","Environment":{"KUBERNETES_PORT":"tcp://10.0.0.1:443","KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP":"tcp://10.0.0.1:443","KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR":"10.0.0.1","KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT":"443","KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO":"tcp","KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST":"10.0.0.1","KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT":"443","KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS":"443"},"EmulateConsole":false,"Creat
eStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]}
      Exit Code:    128
      Started:      Fri, 29 Dec 2017 05:18:41 +0000
      Finished:     Fri, 29 Dec 2017 05:18:41 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  8
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-9l4dp (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          False
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  default-token-9l4dp:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-9l4dp
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age                From                   Message
  ----     ------                 ----               ----                   -------
  Normal   Scheduled              20m                default-scheduler      Successfully assigned getdocumentservice-deployment-528941145-cpt30 to e527bacs9002
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  20m                kubelet, e527bacs9002  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-9l4dp"
  Normal   Pulled                 4m (x9 over 20m)   kubelet, e527bacs9002  Container image "iolregistry.azurecr.io/panviva/doc:v1" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                4m (x9 over 20m)   kubelet, e527bacs9002  Created container
  Warning  Failed                 4m (x9 over 20m)   kubelet, e527bacs9002  Error: failed to start container "getdocumentservice": Error response from daemon: {"message":"container getdocumentservice encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) extra info: {\"ApplicationName\":\"\"
,\"CommandLine\":\"./modules/GetDocumentService/GetDocumentService.exe\",\"User\":\"\",\"WorkingDirectory\":\"C:\\\\app\\\\modules\",\"Environment\":{\"KUBERNETES_PORT\":\"tcp://10.0.0.1:443\",\"KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP\":\"tcp://10.0.0.1:443\",\"KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR\":\"10.0.0.1\",\"KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT\":\"443\",\"KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO\
":\"tcp\",\"KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST\":\"10.0.0.1\",\"KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT\":\"443\",\"KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS\":\"443\"},\"EmulateConsole\":false,\"CreateStdInPipe\":true,\"CreateStdOutPipe\":true,\"CreateStdErrPipe\":true,\"ConsoleSize\":[0,0]}"}
```

Comment: Paul - does not look like an issue with multiple pods starting once. CrashLoopBackOff indicates something wrong with image pull/scheduling. Can you "describe" one of pods and paste relevant errors etc.?

Comment: Updated the question. It is not an image pull issue because when I run the deployment by itself it works. I can run up to four individual deployments and they work but adding more is when it starts to fail likewise combining the deployments together also causes failures

Comment: Can you get the logs from the pods, kubectl logs [-f] [-p] POD [-c CONTAINER]

Comment: Can't get the logs because the container fails to start and so says failed to open log file

Comment: Did you try getting into the container using exec command before the crashLoopBackOff...  again this is because I agree with Vishal, this could possibly be a conflict and we need to analyse what is getting deployed.